# Invalid option for /langversion on C# project build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio is giving me this error: "CS1617 C# Invalid option for /langversion. Use to list supported values" and I do not know how to fix it. I have looked around the internet and I cannot find the fix to it. I have tried many things and I do not know how to work on this, as I cannot build and test my .NET code without building it.

I tried some people with the same error on stackoverflow, and none of the solutions that people gave worked for me, if someone could give me a fix that would work that would be very appreciated. I use visual studio 2022 version 17.1.6

Comment: Show the relevant contents of your .csproj file. Also, show the entire and actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft documents the accepted values for `langversion` in [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1617).

I am using the following in my `.csproj` project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```